# How to display date + time in the keynote slides?

Tags: keynote

[image]

It works perfectly for `TODAY()` (DATE),
but I also want to display current along with the date so I did this :

I added this formula in the bottom of my master slides.

[image]

I got this red exclaimation

[image]

How would one do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NOW function to display both the current date & time, as shown in the picture below, instead of only the current date from the TODAY function in Keynote. Note that the date and time shown in a Keynote table get updated whenever a table is changed or the Keynote file is reopened.

[image]

You can also change how the date & time is displayed through the Format > Cell sidebar menu after selecting the cell with the formula in the table.

P.S. You get the error message in your post because the TIME() function, which would not actually help you in this case and unlike NOW or TODAY functions, requires arguments to work. Just click on the exclamation sign to learn more about the problem if you get such an error message after creating a formula in a Keynote table.